# How to check if a radio button is checked to display a button to continue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two radio buttons to select a shipping method upon checkout. I want to check with jquery if one of these radio buttons checked, then the button to process with checkout will appear, otherwise, it will be hidden.

> **HTML/PHP**

```
<form method="get">
   <label class="ship-method" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">
   <input type="radio" name="dm_shipping_option" id="tttm_courier" value="1" onclick="getCourier(1);" />
   <?php echo $shipping_costs; ?>&euro;&nbsp;<?php echo getValue('name','banners',3); ?>
   <?php echo "<br />"; ?>
   <span class="ship-desc"><?php echo getValue('content','banners',3); ?></span>
   </label>
   <label class="ship-method" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">
   <input type="radio" name="dm_shipping_option" id="client_courier" value="0" onclick="getCourier(0);" />
   <?php echo getValue('name','banners',2); ?>
   <?php echo "<br />"; ?>
   <span class="ship-desc"><?php echo getValue('content','banners',2); ?></span>
   </label>
</form>
```

> **Jquery**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var isCheckedTTCourier = $('#tttm_courier').prop('checked');
        var isCheckedCourier = $('#client_courier').prop('checked');
        if (!isCheckedTTCourier) {
            $("#submit-btn").css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            $("#submit-btn").css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this! I have made a sample snippet for you which works as expected. you can toggle the button based on condition.

```js
function getCourier(id) {
  var isCheckedTTCourier = $('#tttm_courier').prop('checked');

  var isCheckedCourier = $('#client_courier').prop('checked');

  $("#submit-btn").toggle(isCheckedTTCourier || isCheckedCourier);
};
```

```css
#submit-btn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get">
  <label class="ship-method" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;"> Radio Button 1
   <input type="radio" name="dm_shipping_option" id="tttm_courier" value="1" onclick="getCourier(1);" />

   <label class="ship-method" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;"> Radio Button 2
   <input type="radio" name="dm_shipping_option" id="client_courier" value="0" onclick="getCourier(0);" />
   
   <br />
   <br />
    <button id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
if (!isCheckedTTCourier) {
    $("#submit-btn").hide();
} else {
    $("#submit-btn").show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a little change to your code, hope it helps.

```
if($('#tttm_courier').attr('checked', true)){
    $("#submit-btn").css('display','block');
}else {
    $("#submit-btn").css('display','none');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toggle(condition)`:

```
$("#submit-btn").toggle(isCheckedTTCourier || isCheckedCourier);
```

Answer (score 1):

> $(#id).is(':checked')

This will give whether a particular button is checked or not